# Need a solution to search by sales person based on unique territory

Tags: location

I've been researching for hours for a solution, but I can't find a module or example of someone else needing this feature.

I have a list of 20-ish sales people, each person is assigned a range of zip codes. Some of them are entire states, but there are a few sales reps where the state is split between 2-3 people. I need a way for the user to enter in their own location and show which sales rep would be their point of contact.

Anyone have an idea of how I would go about doing that? Location module?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found something that might help you [Locator tutorial](https://www.drupal.org/node/1944648) and use [Location Map](https://www.drupal.org/project/locationmap) if you want to display the results in a map.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.drupal.org/node/1944648 This link might help you out..

Comment: I've used this tutorial before but for this case, I need each dealer/sales rep to be "in charge of" hundreds of zip codes. So the proximity wouldn't really matter. I'm looking for a way to import all of these zip codes (and an easy way to maintain them) without having to manually input each one.

Comment: let me be clear first you need 20 sales person having multiple zip codes assign each of them. and on search if a user inputs their zip code. the corresponding sales person will be listed in the list????

Comment: That's my initial plan-- but I see two downsides:
- Zip codes can change and I don't want to have to actively maintain the database (especially because Canada will be included)
- It'd be nice if they could search by their street address/state as well like with the Location module/geofield combo (but it isn't necessary)

Comment: I suggest you to use some kind of refrence module like user refrence or entityrefrence.. You have to relate each node with with any one user.once you acheive that you can refine your search easily based on that refrences

Comment: one solution i found while working for your question is that you have to user node refrence or refrence or user refrence module for drupal 7.This provide the user refrence field in mange fields of your content type which shows a list of users on the site that you create using views and refrening in this newly created field which list down all the users to refer while creating new node . and while creating your view you can refer those users or sales men to list down with that node on search..